# View Log Failure; Airflow Celery Worker DNS is Incorrect, How Can I Fix It?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, celery, airflow

**Summary**
I'm running Airflow in distributed mode, using Celery Executer. I have two RHEL7 EC2 instances on AWS, a master (webserver, scheduler, flower) and a worker. I cannot view logs through the UI.

**Source of the problem**
(On AWS) the DNS server that I use truncates DNS records by removing the first octet in the generated DNS name.  If an instance IP address is 10.204.224.123 then the DNS A-Record will be IP-204-224-123.xxx.domain.com.

**Effect**
The `hostname` value recorded in the `task_instance` Table is recorded as the DNS record originally provisioned by AWS, which is not correct.

This causes a failure when attempting to view logs through the UI.

```
*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://<incorrect-dns>:8793/log/<dag>/<task>/<log-timestamp>
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker.

*** Reading remote logs...
*** Unsupported remote log location.
```

**Work Arounds**

- If I edit (remove '-10') the url that the UI tries to find the log at, then I can view it in my browser just by entering it into the address bar.
- If I manually modify the `task_instance` table:

  ```
  UPDATE task_instance SET hostname = replace(hostname,'ip-10-','ip-');
  ```

  Then the UI can find them (for dags already run).

**Ask**
How can I programmatically modify the way that worker address is stored? Can someone point me towards the airflow code that handles this? I want the `View Log` page in the UI to work as it's supposed to.

Comment: Just as a work around - you can advertise the 'wrong' DNS hostname on a private hosted zone and then that code would work.

Comment: I don't have control over the DNS server, nor can I interact with private hosted zones. The upstream issue is strictly a given.

Comment: Figured it out.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-static-hostname/
The solution was slightly different for me due to the corporate AMI I use, but that is the general counterpart to what I ended up doing.

Comment: Cool. What host name did you assign to the instance then?  The invalid one?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Airflow 1.9.0+ where support was added for custom logging classes, then you can write your own task log handler that searches for the logs with a modified url format. This is nice because you shouldn't have to directly change any code in Airflow.

The "View Log" [endpoint](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/www/views.py#L691-L724) fetches all the relevant task instances and then gets the name of the log handler from config under `task_log_reader`. It then finds that handler which should be inside the `logging_config_class` to fetch all the logs.

So you'll want to write a custom class that inherits from `airflow.utils.log.FileTaskHandler`, but [forms the log url](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py#L104-L109) differently. Then you'll want write a custom logging config that uses this class. You can copy `airflow.config_templates.airflow_local_settings.DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG` and just change the [class for the file task handler](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py#L104-L109). Perhaps something like this:

```
class AWSFileTaskHandler(FileTaskHandler):

    def _read(self, ti, try_number):
        ti = ti.hostname.replace(hostname,'ip-10-','ip-')
        super(AWSFileTaskHandler, self)._read(ti, try_number)

DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    ... # may have to copy paste this over, I had trouble importing because it then tries to load config, endless cycle
}
MY_LOGGING_CONFIG = DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG.copy()
MY_LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers']['file.task']['class'] = 'foo.bar.AWSFileTaskHandler'
```

Finally, remember to set `logging_config_class = foo.bar.MY_LOGGING_CONFIG` in your airflow config file.